# Xtext 2.7 and JDK version

Tags: eclipse-rcp, xtext

I tried to find information about which level of JDK is recommended  for Xtext. To my regret I did not found official requirements regarding JDK level. My question is which level of JDK shall be used for xtext ?

1.8 or 1.7 or 1.6

Thank you in advance
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

In comparision to Java 8 Java 5 and Java 6 didn't bring real syntax extension. I don't know exactly which version is required for Xtext 2.7, but I recently read something about Xtend (which comes with Xtext). The document said that Xtend lambdas will compile to Java8 lambdas if one wants it. Otherwise it still compiles to Java 5.

From this information I would derive that Xtext needs at least Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "recommended" level, use whatever makes sense for your project. Xtext 2.7 works with anything form Java 5 to Java 8.

Xtext 2.8 will require at least Java 6.